# Always failed to pass the token on the first try, but succeeded on the second try

Tags: groovy, jmeter, parameter-passing, jsr223, threadgroup

The Jmeter I am using is version 5.5, I want to pass the token generated by Thread Group 01, to Thread Group 02. After doing some research, I know how to do it, but it always fails at the first try.

In **Thread Group 01**, I performed the following configuration:

1. **JSON Extractor** to get the token and store it into `bearerToken` variable,
2. JSR223 PostPocessor & groovy to pass token to another thread, I wrote this `${__setProperty(bearerToken,${bearerToken})}`

   [image: JSR223 Post Processor]

In **Thread Group 02**, I performed the following configuration:

1. User Defined Variables, then using `__property()` function

   [image: property function]
2. And use it as a header

   [image: http header]

Every time it is run for the first time, the http-request in Thread Group 02 always fails to run because it doesn't get a token. But if it is run again for the second time, it will succeed.

[image: view result tree]

The yellow box is the first time Thread Group 01 (Login & Debug Sampler) and Thread Group 02 (Index) are run, the blue box is the condition when run for the second time.

I thought initially Thread Group 02 was run first before Thread Group 01, that's why I enabled the "Run Thread Groups consecutively (i.e. one at a time)" option in the Test Plan. I ran it and checked the listener, the result was the same, Thread Group 01 (Login & Debug Sampler) was successfully run but Thread Group 02 (Index) was not successful because it did not get an access token.

[image: Run Thread Groups consecutively]

nb:I can't show the image because it needs at least 10 reputation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Amend your JSR223 PostProcessor code to use [`props` and `vars` shorthands](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes) instead of inlining the function there:

   ```
   props.put('bearerToken', vars.get('bearerToken'))
   ```
2. In your HTTP Header Manager use [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) as

   ```
   ${__P(bearerToken,)}
   ```

Comment: Hi @Dmitri T, thanks for answering my question. It's work for me, and after came across with this article about [User Defined Variables](https://jmetervn.com/2016/12/09/user-defined-variables/) I know why my setup doesn't work. I use UDF in every thread group with the expectation that it will be executed when the group thread is started. Turns out I was wrong, the UDF will be executed first -- in whatever order it's in -- when the test plan is performed. After that, I tried it directly in the HTTP Header Manager and it worked immediately. And your answer makes me even more confident.

Comment: The [documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables) is also mention about it.